# Pass values/data from one screen to another in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: screen, caliburn.micro

I've been using the Caliburn.Micro framework lately. I have a ShellView and two screens, we'll call them ScreenOne and ScreenTwo. I am trying to pass data from ScreenOne to ScreenTwo. I have looked extensively on the web and I can't believe this is so hard to find. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Inject a SharedViewModel singleton into ScreenOneViewModel and ScreenTwoViewModel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative could be to use the Event Aggregator and use a publish/subscribe technique to communicate between the screens. In the [event aggregator tutorial](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator) there is an example where two view models both publish their own events and subscribe to the other view model's events. The example is further elaborated in one source code sample, *HelloEventAggregator*.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `ShellViewModel` is a conductor, and has references to both `ScreenOneViewModel` and `ScreenTwoViewModel`, you can either pass the data to the view models at their point of construction (i.e. when you instantiate those view models) as constructor parameters, or at any later point via a public method or property.

An example that uses view model factories:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive 
{
    private readonly IScreenOneViewModelFactory screenOneViewModelFactory;

    private readonly IScreenTwoViewModelFactory screenTwoViewModelFactory;

    public ShellViewModel(
            IScreenOneViewModelFactory screenOneViewModelFactory,
            IScreenTwoViewModelFactory screenTwoViewModelFactory)
    {
       this.screenOneViewModelFactory = screenOneViewModelFactory;
       this.screenTwoViewModelFactory = screenTwoViewModelFactory;

       var screenOneViewModel = this.screenOneViewModelFactory.CreateViewModel();
       this.ActivateItem(screenOneViewModel);
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
       // Get data from screen one
       var myData = this.screenOneViewModel.Data;

       // Create a screen two view model from the screen one data
       var screenTwoViewModel = 
            this.screenTwoViewModelFactory.CreateViewModel(myData);
       this.ActivateItem(screenTwoViewModel);           
    }
}
```